# Display image according div tag width and height style properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this sample to illustrate what I need :

#### css

```
.thumb-image { 
    height:450px;
    width:450px;
}
#image-container {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
}
```

#### html

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img src="Forest.jpg" class="thumb-image" alt="Forest" style="cursor: pointer;"  />
</div>
```

#### js

```
$('.thumb-image').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('thumb-image');
});
```

Here the image is downloaded from the client at its full size. I don't use cached images and in order to simulate thumbnails, I just apply `width` and `height` to each image. However I want the user to be able to see larger image when he clicks on it, so I found that using `$(this).toggleClass('thumb-image');` is most appropriate because this gives me the ability to enlarge the image and then turn it back to the predefined dimensions which is ok. But some images are too large so I want to restrict the `width` of the displayed image to something acceptable (which in my case is 800px) and also I want to be able to control the place where the enlarged image is shown so I created a `<div id="image-container">` where I want to appear my enlarged image.

The problem is that I don't know how to force the image to occupy only the space of the div without enlarging the div as it happens now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make sure no images are wider than its container with something like this;

```
#image-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The best solution would be to not serve images bigger than you need, save some bandwidth ;)

Comment: I think, if the image is less than 800px, then it is stretched.

Comment: @maximkou What makes you think this?

Comment: Thanks, I have this in mind but I try to go one step at a time, there are a lot of things I don't know and I need something to show quickly, even though it's not the optimal solution. I have in mind making real thumbnails but it's something that I left for future optimizations.

Comment: @xec, or rather do not stretch, and is blank space.

Comment: No stretching, just check, blank space, but the proportions are kept which is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can user `overflow:hidden` in your `image-container` div or also assign 100% width to img tag.

Suggestion :-

It is not an optimum way to do this. if your image-container having less width than you should resize your image using image thumbnail library. there are number of benefits to use resize image instead of control height width using html and css.

- small size image take less time to page load
- image looks good. without stretch

Comment: Thanks. I may look in some thumbnail library, never worked with one though. However I need to implement basic functionalities right now and leave optimization parts for later.

Comment: Yeah . Cool :) . I just remind the thing I hope you know all basic thing

Comment: Well I don't know a lot, but posting here helps a lot. And I really appreciate when people like you gives  me directions on how I can do things better. You can learn a lot very fast that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .thumb-image {
        height: 450px;
        width: 450px;
    }

    #image-container {
        max-width: 800px;
        height: auto;
    }

    #image-container img {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```